# Applying function based on condition on pandas dataframe series

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Pandas

My dataframe:

**df**

```
A            B
first        True 
second       False
third        False
fourth       True
fifth        False
```

**Desired output**

```
A            B          C
first        True       en
second       False      
third        False
fourth       True       en
fifth        False
```

I am trying to apply a function to column `C` only when the `B` column is `True`.

**What I use**

```
if (df['B'] == True)):
    df['C'] = df['A'].apply(
        lambda x: TextBlob(x).detect_language())
```

But I get an error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

**What I've tried**

```
df['B'].bool()
df['B'] is True
df['B'] == 'True'
```

But the error persists, not sure how I would form a statement saying 'only where column B is True'.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If want missing values for no matched rows filter rows before `apply` for processing only rows with `True`s:

```
df['C'] = df.loc[df['B'], 'A'].apply(lambda x: TextBlob(x).detect_language())
print (df)
        A      B    C
0   first   True   en
1  second  False  NaN
2   third  False  NaN
3  fourth   True   en
4   fifth  False  NaN
```

Or if need empty strings for non matched values, but `apply` processing all columns:

```
df['C'] = np.where(df['B'], df['A'].apply(lambda x: TextBlob(x).detect_language()), '')
print (df)
        A      B   C
0   first   True  en
1  second  False    
2   third  False    
3  fourth   True  en
4   fifth  False
```

Comment: so there is no need to use `==True` in any form? I thought that the statement `df['B']` means that the row is not empty, not that the value in it is not `False`.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - If there are boolean then it is not necessary, also for `df['B'] == False` is used `~df['B']`